# Аналог конструкции nginx на apache

Tags: apache, nginx

Можно ли на apache повторить настройку для nginx

```
location / { root /var/www/каталог_сайта/static/build; }
location ~ \.html$ {
    root /var/www/корневая_директория/static/build;
    expires 10m;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Или хотя бы первую часть

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос, а не писать дополнения в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

примерно так:

```
AliasMatch "^/(.*)\.html$" "/var/www/корневая_директория/static/build/$1"
```

Подробнее тут: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch

Comment: Исправил десяток раз, прошу прощения и пару лет не работал с Апачем, нужно проверить...

Comment: вы даете ответ с `Alias`, ссылку в документацию даете на `AliasMatch`, c Апачем давно не работали, решение не тестировали. Может не надо такие ответы давать, тем более что `Alias` не работает с regex-ом...

Comment: почему не надо давать?

Comment: @defrag спасибо, поправил AliasMatch

Comment: Не надо давать - потому что, 1 - вы не уверены в ответе, 2 - ответ не тестировался. А этом случае надо быть очень уверенным, чтобы не тестировать. 3 - ответ все равно не верный. 4 - смысл такого ответа равен нулю, а скорее даже вредит, потому что запутывает ситуацию.